# nested sql sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have three fields as below:

```
f1  f2  f3
b   x   100.22
c   y   150.15
a   x   240.35
a   y   130.25
b   y   789.34
c   x   199.89
```

I want to sort them like this:

```
f1  f2  f3
b   y   789.34
b   x   100.22
a   x   240.35
a   y   130.25
c   x   199.89
c   y   150.15
```

The main sort should be done based on f3, so the group of f1 values that have bigger sum value in f3 should be upper (descending order).
Also the values of f3 should be ordered descending in their own group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the sum using a subquery and then use this for the `order by`:

```
select f1, f2, f3
from (select t.*, sum(f3) over (partition by f1) as sumf1
      from table t
     ) t
order by sumf1 desc, f1, f3 desc;
```

Actually, you don't need the subquery (although I prefer to use them with window functions):

```
select f1, f2, f3
from table t
order by sum(f3) over (partition by f1) desc, f1, f3 desc;
```